# Shell Scripting: Convert file string to be usable in a command

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed

I'm stuck on figuring out a way to take text of a file name and converting it into a string that can be usable in commands.

I would like to take a file name (for example: `[foo] bar - foo.mkv`) and add backslashes to spaces, square brackets, and any other characters (for example `\[foo\]\ bar\ -\ foo.mkv`) so that they are usable in a command such as `mv`.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You do not need to do this, your file name is 100% usable as is, you just need to quote it when you use it just like you should quote ALL shell variables unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a need for that. You could enclose the filename variable in double quotes and the commands would handle the rest.

```
$ touch "[foo] bar - foo.mkv"
$ ls
[foo] bar - foo.mkv
$ mv "[foo] bar - foo.mkv" "abcd"
$ ls
abcd
```

So just enclose the string in double quotes and it must solve your problem:

```
mv "$oldname" "$newname"
```

There's rarely a need, but if you want to have substitutions you can use this:

```
$ printf '%q' "[foo] bar - foo.mkv"
\[foo\]\ bar\ -\ foo.mkv
```